# I have an Iterable<? extends String> and need an Iterable<String>

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface (Guava CacheBuilder) that gives me an `Iterable<? extends String>`. I eventually need to call a method that takes an `Iterable<String>`. It seems that I can't pass the `Iterable<? extends String>` directly, which is really annoying.

My best solution so far is to copy the Iterable into some collection.

```
Iterable<? extends String> annoyingIterable = ...;
Iterable<String> niceIterable = new ArrayList<>(annoyingIterable);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `? extends String` doesn't make sense since `String` is a final class... So it will always be `Iterable<String>` only... You could just cast it... But the correct fix would be to modify the interface in the Guava library...

Comment: @Codebender -- it's usually [because](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Tight_Bound) the API is generic, returning `Iterable<? extends T>`; then T is substituted with `String`. I agree to just cast it.

Comment: Intuitively, `Iterable<B>` can always be used as `Iterable<A>`, if `B<:A`, though Java does not support the subtyping relationship. We *can* safely do the cast, preferably with a helper method. See [Missing Wildcard](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Missing_Wildcards). Note that `Iterable` is a functional interface with just one abstract method; try passing `annoyingIterable::iterator` to the method that expects `Iterable<String>` :)

Comment: `annoyingIterable.iterator()` is also an `Iterable<? extends String>`